# RFM95 digital io to control mute on PAM8403 to get rid of hiss while receiving

Tags: interrupt, esp32

I am building a solution with an ESP32, a PAM8403 amp, a parallel TFT display, and a RFM95 LoRa module. All works great but I want to get rid of the noise that is generated when Lora is in receive mode.

I can do this by pulling pin 12 low on the PAM8403, which mutes all sound. However I have ran out of output pins on my ESP32, and it's too late to use a IO expander as the PCB has been built.

My initial idea was to use the RX/TX pins on the ESP32 when the unit was out of diagnostics mode. However if I can avoid this then that would be great. In my code when I issue `Lora.sleep() / Lora.idle()` the hissing goes away.

So I started to wonder if I could just trigger the mute function through another logic state that goes low when LoRa is idle and high when sleeping (allowing the mute to deactivate).

I am using the `LoRa` library by Sandeep Mistry, and I was wondering if I could use `DIO1, DIO2`, etc. as an IO PIN to control mute. If not, is it possible to use any of the already connected pins to behave in the desired way?

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: It looks like not. The DIO pins can be set to indicate specific events, none of which are sleep / idle.

Comment: Thanks @Majenko - would there be any events that can be spoofed from the user side (ESP32 / programatically) that would hold one of the pins Low? During the mute period I do not want to use the lora board, just use it to change states...

Comment: Actually what if I disconnect the reset pin and connect it to the ESP32, would this not free as PIN up? or are there issues down the road in not having a dedicated reset pin for the RFM95..

Comment: Yes, it looks like you could re-purpose reset. The library only uses that in `begin()` and there is a special case checking to see if the reset pin has been set to `-1` in which case it ignores it. So you could tie nRESET to +3.3V and use your reset GPIO pin for another purpose if you use the `setPins()` function to change nRESET to -1.

Comment: Thanks @Majenko I knew there would be a way somewhere.... so I have my TFT Reset and capacitive touch Reset connected together. Should I connect the Reset for rfm to these or is there actually no need to have a reset connection? Or even the esp32 reset...

Comment: Reset can put things into a known good state, so it's handy to have. Sure, one big master reset to reset all your peripherals at startup is good. I'd avoid the ESP32's reset though as that is fiddled with when uploading code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way you can use the DIO pins to indicate sleep mode. They can only be set to indicate certain events, and sleep/idle is not one of them.

However the nRESET pin is optional, and you can use the `setPins()` function in the LoRa library to change which pin it's connected to - and one option is to set it to `-1` in which case the library ignores it (this must be run *before* `.begin()` is called) as it's only used during `begin()` to initially reset the LoRa module.

You could either tie nRESET HIGH (to 3.3V) to never reset it, or couple it with the reset signal of another peripheral so it gets reset at the same time - just be careful with your initialisation order in this case so you don't reset the module after configuring it...

Comment: Ah good to know that’s what reset actually does. I have since implemented ad sound effects are now sound much better without the surrounding hiss.